# nuxtServerInit doesnt get called from index.js

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a request to my server but as per the document nuxtServerInit is not working. I currently have index.js only inside of store folder. I havent imported vuex though. I can see my base states. But nuxtServerInit is not being called although its inside of index.js actions object.

```js
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({commit}){
        let response = await this.$axios.$get('categories')
        commit('SET_CATEGORIES', response.data)
    }
}
```

non asynchronous nuxtServerInit() doesnt work either.

```
export const actions = {
    nuxtServerInit({commit}){
        console.log("testing")
        
    }
}
```

index.js
[image: index js file here]

### issue solved

I restarted the server it didnt worked. I quit my bash and try again bam it works. so basically try restarting the server

Comment: Is actions included as a property on your Vuex store? Please show exactly how this actions object is included in your store. Also please show how you are registering the store in your application.

Comment: i havent done anything to register the store. I just created a index.js file on store folder. I have updated the description with index.js file @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: Documentation https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/ that async nuxtServerInit must return a promise

Comment: how can i use it in my case? async await is a promise too right?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky non asynchronous nuxtServerInit doesnt work either. updated the description.